# Live Photo saving automatically

Tags: swift

New to Xcode, trying to make an app to download live wallpapers. 
I used LivePhotoDemo from github for all the codes. My problem is that when the page loads in it shows the live photo but saves two copies of it in my photo lib And i cant seem to figure out how to get a save button to do it instead (and only one copy)

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import PhotosUI
import MobileCoreServices


struct FilePaths {
static let documentsPath : AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory,.userDomainMask,true)[0] as AnyObject
struct VidToLive {
    static var livePath = FilePaths.documentsPath.appending("/")
}
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, 
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
//@IBOutlet var livePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView!

@IBOutlet var livePhotoView: PHLivePhotoView!
    {
    didSet {
        loadVideoWithVideoURL(Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video", withExtension: "mov")!)
    }
}

func loadVideoWithVideoURL(_ videoURL: URL) {
    livePhotoView.livePhoto = nil
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL)
    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = NSValue(time: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration)/2, preferredTimescale: asset.duration.timescale))
    generator.generateCGImagesAsynchronously(forTimes: [time]) { [weak self] _, image, _, _, _ in
        if let image = image, let data = UIImage(cgImage: image).pngData() {
            let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            let imageURL = urls[0].appendingPathComponent("image.jpg")
            try? data.write(to: imageURL, options: [.atomic])

            let image = imageURL.path
            let mov = videoURL.path
            let output = FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath
            let assetIdentifier = UUID().uuidString
            let _ = try? FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: output, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: output + "/IMG.JPG")
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: output + "/IMG.MOV")

            } catch {

            }
            JPEG(path: image).write(output + "/IMG.JPG",
                                    assetIdentifier: assetIdentifier)
            QuickTimeMov(path: mov).write(output + "/IMG.MOV",
                                          assetIdentifier: assetIdentifier)

            //self?.livePhotoView.livePhoto = LPDLivePhoto.livePhotoWithImageURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath.stringByAppendingString("/IMG.JPG")), videoURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath.stringByAppendingString("/IMG.MOV")))
            //self?.exportLivePhoto()
            _ = DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                PHLivePhoto.request(withResourceFileURLs: [ URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.MOV"), URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.JPG")],
                                    placeholderImage: nil,
                                    targetSize: self!.view.bounds.size,
                                    contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit,
                                    resultHandler: { (livePhoto, info) -> Void in
                                        self?.livePhotoView.livePhoto = livePhoto
                                        self?.exportLivePhoto()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

 @IBAction func Savephoto(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
  }
  func exportLivePhoto () {
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({ () -> Void in
        let creationRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.forAsset()
        let options = PHAssetResourceCreationOptions()


        creationRequest.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.pairedVideo, fileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.MOV"), options: options)
        creationRequest.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.photo, fileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.JPG"), options: options)

    }, completionHandler: { (success, error) -> Void in
        if !success {
            NSLog((error?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
    })
}
}
```

i have the main view linked to the IBOutlet at the top and the save button to the IBAction near the bottom. I literally dont know much about coding besides some HTML and C++ YEARS ago. I only kinda know how to look through codes and try to make sense of everything. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong and where. thank you so much!

Comment: This seems to make a mov and jpg copy.  Is this what you mean by duplicate?  creationRequest.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.pairedVideo, fileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.MOV"), options: options)
        creationRequest.addResource(with: PHAssetResourceType.photo, fileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: FilePaths.VidToLive.livePath + "/IMG.JPG"), options: options)

Comment: yeah, i was thinking the same thing that its saving one of each maybe?? They both come out as a live photo... and for the IBAction... i had just done some looking around the internet before commenting, but i have no idea how to do that haha. thank you so much for he help. Im going crazy

Comment: im just not sure where to put the func exportLivePhoto if its not there. if i change anything or move it out the code above "self?.exportLivePhoto()" gives an error and says "Value of type 'ViewController; has no member 'exportLivePhoto'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things to get you unstuck here.

Issue 1: How do I get my save button to call exportLivePhoto():

Your IBAction for your button should look something like this:

```
  @IBAction func savePhotoTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("in savePhotoTapped | start"
    exportLivePhoto()
  }
```

Make sure this action is connected to your button that you created in your storyboard.

Issue 2: Multiple saves:

These lines look like they save a jpg and mov version of the image.  If you only want one comment out the other.

```
try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: output + "/IMG.JPG")
try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: output + "/IMG.MOV")
```

Also try cleaning up your code so its more easily readable in the future.

Comment: omg, thank you...So the IBAction now works to save the mov as a live photo. But upon opening that view controller it still saves 2 other versions, both live photos. I tried to comment out one of the lines and xcode froze up and ran a ton of errors trying to save the MOV as a live photo. so i know right there it automatically is trying to save it. I (think) I need both of those lines in there to write a JPG and MOV. its a big step for me so far. i really, really wanna thank you so much for all the help you have given me up to this point. I just have to figure out why it saves opening that page.

Comment: i tried to comment out the .MOV line and thats when i got the errors.... i just tried the JPG line and nothing changed. live image still appeared and double saved upon opening that view. hmmm...

Comment: the solution wasnt the try fileManager codes... it was one single line at the bottom of that func. self.exportLivePhoto() .... i commented that out the other day just messing around with things and it stopped double saving on opening that page. i kinda forgot about it because it wasnt working with my button either so i figured i needed it, but then again my IBAction was set up incorrectly. now that i fixed it i commented that line out again and BAM, it works. i cant thank you enough.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  This is an amazing guide to get you started with Swift btw: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html.  

Feel free to accept my response as the correct answer if you want.